# VSCode - Popup to find file by name when pressing shift

Tags: visual-studio-code

Every time I press (and release) the shift key, visual studio code shows me the popup to find a file by name. I checked all keybinds, but there is no keybind which is triggered when only pressing shift. It is very annoying, as I type quite fast while coding and while I press the shift key long enough to type a capital, it also triggers the popup. When typing slowly I don't get the popup, but this is of course not the solution. I already tried reinstalling but still no luck... I hope anyone can help my out with my problem!

Comment: have you tried the key binding debugging to see what command is called for which key

Comment: If with this you mean going to Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts > Record Keys and then pressing shift, then yes, I did try that, and nothing came up.

Comment: no read the keybinding doc page